# Binding to (Validation.Errors).CurrentItem does not work with TextBox (works with DataGrid)

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, binding

I am trying to bind ToolTip property to a (Validation.Errors).CurrentItem in code. I allready did that with DataGrid like:

```
var grid = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
grid.SetValue(Grid.ToolTipProperty, new Binding() {
        RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(DataGridRow), 1),
        Path = new PropertyPath("(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent")
});
```

That works, error sign appears in row header with tool tip (some error text).

When I try to do the same with text box tool tip does not appear:

```
grid.SetValue(Grid.ToolTipProperty, new Binding() {
     ElementName = textBox1.Name, // tried with relative source also...
     Path = new PropertyPath("(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent")
});
```

Regards,

Vale

Comment: Is the TextBox inside the Grid (I mean, inside a cell) or is outside the grid?

Comment: Grid is just a base for error sign. So tool tip is over a Grid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you may be able to use the [Binding.Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source.aspx) property. Like so:

```
grid.SetValue(Grid.ToolTipProperty, new Binding() {
     Source = textBox1,
     Path = new PropertyPath("(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent")
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that you need the CurrentItem in there

I've never done validation binding in code behind before, but my XAML for TextBox validation looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="ValidatingTextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding 
                    Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, 
                    RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Yes, that is binding to a TextBox itself, but I want to bind to error sign (grid with Ellipse and TextBlock inside, looks like (!) ) that is placed near TextBox

Comment: @Vale Set the Template in the Trigger instead of the ToolTip and overwrite it to show your Grid and Ellipse

Comment: @Rachel: CurrentItem lets you bind and not get errors in the console when there are no validation errors. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260616/why-does-wpf-style-to-show-validation-errors-in-tooltip-work-for-a-textbox-but-f