# Why does AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent now (VS2017 15.4) cause intellisense errors?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I've been using the following error adorner template for a long time now:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorAdornerTemplateStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Grid ClipToBounds="False" >
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Margin="-1" 
         ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=adornedElement, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent }">
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="adornedElement" />
        </Border>
        <Polygon Points="15,15 15,0 0,0"
                 Fill="Red"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=adornedElement, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent }"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

... and it works at run-time just fine (as far as I can tell).

However, after a flurry of upgrades to VS and WPF and NET Standard 2 in the past month, I've noticed that the intellisense in my syles xaml file is giving me the following error for the `CurrentItem` identifier:

**The property 'CurrentItem' was not found in type 'ReadOnlyObservableCollection'.**

Is this just a nuisance VS bug or is VS alerting me to some kind of change in the WPF subsystem that I need to adapt to?

Comment: Does the result differ if you use the `/` for current item binding? Like `Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent`.

Comment: Wow, that actually solved it (both design-time and run-time work error-free). If you post an answer I will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` itself doesn't expose a `CurrentItem` property. Instead, the `CurrentItem` is a concept of the `CollectionView` that is internally created when a collection of items is bound in WPF.

There is some [special support to access the `CurrentItem`](https://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/09/03/bindtocurrent) of a collection by using `/` in the binding path.

Change the binding path to `Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent` to utilize this support.

Comment: Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)/CurrentItem.ErrorContent will do the trick?

Comment: @gbianchi no, the `/` replaces `.CurrentItem.`, it doesn't go together.