# How to do a simple validation with IDataErrorInfo and data annotations

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I have `Model` with one property. This `Model` inherits from a base model which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `IDataInfoError`.
Above my property I have `ValidationAttribute` Required, with an error message I want to bring into a tooltip.
Therefore I have a textbox in my view.

My proplem: When the textbox is empty, the validation works. The textbox has a red border.
When the textbox is empty and I write something in it, I get a error in my output window.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'Item[]' value (type 'ValidationError') from '(Validation.Errors)' (type 'ReadOnlyObservableCollection`1'). BindingExpression:Path=(0)[0].ErrorContent; DataItem='TextBox' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'ToolTip' (type 'Object') ArgumentOutOfRangeException:'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: index'

To reproduce the error:
**Models**

```
public class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public string Error { get { return null; } }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

            if (Validator.TryValidateProperty(
                    GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue(this)
                    , new ValidationContext(this) { MemberName = columnName }
                    , validationResults))
                return null;

            return validationResults.First().ErrorMessage;
        }
    }
}

public class Model : ModelBase
{
    private string name;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Wrong")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;

            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                    Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Margin="10" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `ValidationError` at position 0 when your indexer returns `null`. Binding to `(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent` instead of `(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent` should fix the binding error:

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                    Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" />
```

Comment: I use Path=(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent, does using CurrentItem make a difference?

Comment: / is the current item and preferable imo. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47185638/why-does-adornedelement-validation-errors-currentitem-errorcontent-now-vs2017